# How I can perform accelerated testing of my PCB board by own?

Tags: pcb, opto-isolator, temperature, proximity-sensor, stress-testing

I am working on a project in which there are system components listed below as module:

8 ultrasonic sensors 12-30 V (Sensor module)
3 DC motors (Drive module)
35 V to 5 V buck converter and a 35 V - 5 V isolated DC-DC converter (Power module)
1 Microcontroller (Controller module)
2 Encoder (Encoder module)

I am using optocoupler for isolating my microcontroller from sensor input voltage and giving signal to motor driver

I want to know How I can test capability of my circuit for example

- sensor switching with high frequency and read by MCU on high temperature (100 Celsius)
- Effect of temperature (100 Celsius) on performance of motor driver in terms of peak output
  current
- Performance of microcontroller on high temperature (100 Celsius)

I can't afford instruments and labs so for now I am using enclosed wooden box and using relays to emulate sensors for switching with high speed and using high watt bulb to increase the temperature in the box and monitoring temperature using temperature sensor and talking data on serial monitor still I have doubt on precise measurement and logs so can you suggest  me how I can perform this test  better and take logs

Comment: I've used an enclosure and lamps before so, it's not too shabby providing you monitor temperature and keep it reasonably stable.

Comment: a bit of insulation and some aluminium foil helps